# Roundup in an update sql query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a sql column that is set to money, this has four numbers after the decimal point. I am calculating this column in an update query, I would like to roundup this column. example: 2388.6796, should be 2389

```
Math.Ceiling(0.5);
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET [ThirdPartyRate] = 'Ceiling(" + GridView1.Rows[SelectedIndex].Cells[6].Text.ToString() + "' * [Price]) WHERE [Supplier] like '" + GridView1.Rows[SelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString() + "' ", con);
```

Comment: Which SQL? SQL Sever?

Comment: Yes, it is sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
CEILING ( numeric_expression )
```

In principle you then do: `UPDATE TABLE Products SET rounded_val=CEILING(not_rounded_val);`

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET [ThirdPartyRate] = CEILING(" +
     GridView1.Rows[SelectedIndex].Cells[6].Text.ToString() + 
     " * [Price]) WHERE [Supplier] like '" + 
     GridView1.Rows[SelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text.ToString() + "' ", con);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I amend this to the above query ?

Comment: Please see my edit above. it runs without errors, however  nothing happens at all.

Comment: @user3012159:Maybe your update clause prevents updates? I have also made an update to the command which I realize was incorrect. I changed 'CEILING()' to CEILING().